# How to timestamp output text files

Tags: python, api, timestamp

This seems relevant but I cannot decipher this and apply it to my problem.

[Python output file with timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867986/python-output-file-with-timestamp)

After going through API authorization, I want this website to dump my data every time I call coinbase.py.  Here are my relevant lines:

```
transdata =  get_http('https://coinbase.com/api/v1/transfers').read()

f1 = open('./DUMP.txt', 'w+')

f1.write( transdata )
```

This will overwrite DUMP.txt every time its called.  How can I ask python to assign the output file a new name each time this module is calld, conserving the old outputs...and make the name as logical as I can (perhaps with a time and date of the call)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepend a linux timestamp by using [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/time.html#time.time) and converting the float to an integer:

```
import time

transdata =  get_http('https://coinbase.com/api/v1/transfers').read()
f1 = open('{}_DUMP.txt'.format(int(time.time())), 'w+')
f1.write( transdata )
```

I'd use the `with`-statment so your file is actually handled correctly:

```
import time

with open("{}_DUMP.txt".format(int(time.time()), 'w+') as out:
    out.write(get_http('https://coinbase.com/api/v1/transfers').read())
```

The [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/time.html) and [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html) modules provide all you need for handling time on python.

Or if you want a date and time, a quick way to do that is to use [`datetime.datetime.now()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now):

```
from datetime import datetime

with open("{}_DUMP.txt".format(datetime.datetime.now(), 'w+') as out:
    out.write(get_http('https://coinbase.com/api/v1/transfers').read())
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I can best understand your first suggestion, so I tried this first. I replaced my 3 lines with yours and the resulting error was:

http://pastebin.com/MargMCnX

Comment: @user3588447 sorry about that, there was a parenthesis in the wrong place. Fixed it.

Comment: Worked.  Beautiful, Thank you very much.  This is all very helpful thanks guys!

Comment: Here's the entire program...with your fix. This resulted in an output called: 1398849448_DUMP.txt  https://github.com/Altoidnerd/Python-Crypto-API/blob/master/coinbase_dump.py

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `tempfile` https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html which allows creation of unique file, even with defined name prefix.

But what you describe is usually resolved by dumping the data into one log file, you do not get you directory cluttered with too many files.

Comment: Yes, append. You will probably need some method how to mark the request boundary. Or you can use logging module from python - it is very powerful and is worth learning, it will pay back.